# Using substr() and strlen() to get a file name

Tags: php

Below is my code. If `$varPath` is `../../folder1/home/` and If `$varNam` is `house.png`
I need `$name` to be `house`. How can I fix this?

```
$varPath = htmlentities('../../folderA/'.$_POST['sVar']).'/');
$varExt = '*.*';
$varNam = glob($varPath.$varExt);

$name = substr($varNam,strlen($varPath),strpos($varNam, '.') - strlen($varPath);
```

Comment: Look at the phpinfo and basename functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$varPath = '../../folder1/home/';
echo basename($varPath);
```

**Output:**
home

EDIT:

In order to remove any extension use pathinfo

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('../../folder1/home/house.png');
echo $path_parts['filename'];
```

**Output:** house

Comment: The OP is asking about removing file extensions, not extract the folder name.

Comment: @Theolodis Edited, thanks, didn't pay attention.

Comment: No problem, but consider taking your time to understand the question and write a good answer. That's worth way more than trying to go for the easy reputation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Improved answer

```
<?php
$path = '/var/www/html/project/images/house.png';
$pathinfo = pathinfo($path);

echo str_replace(".{$pathinfo['extension']}", '', $pathinfo['basename']);
```

This will produce "house" no matter what the extension.

Comment: He does probably need to remove file endings, any of them.. e.g. /x/y/file1.jpeg, y/x/file2.png, etc...

Comment: `path_info['filename']` does not contain the extension, does it?

Comment: @Theolodis Oh, that one exists too? Since when? :D

Comment: True. Missed that completely....